# EF Core 3.1 produces incorrect query translation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have the following EF Core 3.1 statement:

```
  var orders = await _dbContext.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderReceivers)
                                      .Where(o => o.BooleanFlag1 && o.OrderState == OrderState.SomeState && o.OrderReceivers.Any(o => o.BooleanFlag2))
                                      .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

and this is the generated SQL Server query:

```
SELECT /*All column names here*/
FROM [Schema].[Orders] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN [Schema].[OrderReceivers] AS [o0] ON [o].[Id] = [o0].[OrderId]
WHERE (([o].[ShouldSendBlackList] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([o].[OrderState] = 2)) AND EXISTS (
SELECT 1
    FROM [Schema].[OrderReceivers] AS [o1]
    WHERE ([o].[Id] = [o1].[OrderId]) AND ([o1].[BooleanFlag2] = '1'))
ORDER BY [o].[Id], [o0].[Id]
```

The problem with the generated SQL Query is this part:

> ([o1].[BooleanFlag2] = '1')

Because this causes the second where clause to be always false!
Any ideas on what is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `BooleanFlag2` is mapped to provider string type via [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Comment: True. That solves the problem.